# Repeating alarm canceled after a few days

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-doze

I'm having a problem with a very simple app that shows a notification once a day.  To do that I am simply doing this:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = [pending Intent to a Service]
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, DateTimeUtil.getTomorrowAtEight(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

This works for a few days and then stops working, on a device running Android 6.0 (LG G4).

`adb -d shell dumpsys alarm` shows that indeed my alarm is not in the list of "Pending alarm batches".

I don't have this problem on a device running Android 5.1 (Samsung S4).

I'm guessing this has something to do with Doze Mode or App Stand by, but as far as I can tell (correct me if I'm wrong), alarms can be delayed, which is fine for my use case, but are not supposed to be cancelled!

Ideas?

Comment: try use Inexact with rescheduling in onHandleIntent

Comment: @DimaRostopira But why? Shouldn't it work?

Comment: do you have a spare time to think about "Why"? :D I don't really. The only thing I understand - you should never rely on system. Neither with GCMNetworkManager, nor with AlarmManager, nor with JobScheduler.